# Operation "timing out" during new item creation in Sitecore Editor

Tags: sitecore

I've created a command in the Sitecore Editor that automatically builds out up to 25 items at a time. The problem that I'm experiencing is that the operation just "hangs" and does not complete.  I don't think it's an error because I've added error handling and logging.

I'm getting the following error message "The operation could not be completed.  Your session may have been lost due to a time-out or a server failure.  Try again."

How can I increase the "time-out" duration (if this is a setting somewhere) - or is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: Please provide sample code, even if its partially redacted. Is it an "event handler" or a "command template"?

Comment: Is this now the original version of your more recent question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913860/command-timing-out-during-sitecore-automated-item-creation

Answer (score 0):

Long running operations will time out eventually depending on your IIS settings, usually after 20 mins. Instead, you should run your commands as a scheduled task, as they run in the background, with no waiting for the IIS request.

However, it seemes strange that inserting 25 items is such a long operation that the browser times out. You might have another issue in your code.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I am attempting to create 275 new items in the one command.  It's definately timeing out, because on the first attempt, it creates about 90% of the items, and times out while the command is running (IE crashes).  On the second attempt, it creates the 16 items that it missed the first time, but it does not time out.  I don't know if I want to run this as a scheduled task, as users may need to use the feature more frequently.